# Как найти доменное имя по ссылке?

Tags: python, re

Пытаюсь с помощью регулярных строк найти доменные имена по ссылкам. На каких-то ссылках корректно работает, а где-то нет.

Пример:
Есть ссылка
`https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

Мне нужно найти доменное имя:

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
```

Я использую следующее регулярное выражение:

```
.*[://].*[/]{1}
```

Но код почему-то находит мне вот эту часть -

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/
```

Хотя при использовании других ссылок всё работает как положено.
Ссылка

```
https://vc.ru/new
```

Что нашёл по регулярной строке -

```
 https://vc.ru/
```

Проблема в том, что какие-то ссылки корректно обрабатываются, а какие-то нет. В чём проблема?

P.S. В ответах на форуме не нашёл подходящего вопроса. Только поиск домена без https/http. Мне нужен поиск вместе с протоколом

Comment: Все обрабатывает корректно  - ищет текст от начала до последнего символа /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте ["ленивый" квантификатор](https://habr.com/ru/articles/68345/) `.+?` и удалите ненужные квадратные скобки

```
import re

for txt in ['https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask', 'https://vc.ru/new','ftp://public.ftp-servers.example.com/mydirectory/myfile.txt']:
    print(re.search(r'.*://.+?/', txt)[0])
```

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
https://vc.ru/
ftp://public.ftp-servers.example.com/
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогло. Но только почему квадратные скобки не нужны? Они же говорят, что нужно искать тот символ, что внутри них находится?

Comment: [Квадратные скобки предназначены для задания подмножества символов. Квадратные скобки внутри регулярного выражения, считаются одним символом, который может принимать значения, перечисленные внутри этих скобок](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bash_scripting_guide/c11895.html). В частности, подвыражение `[/]` то же самое, что и '/`

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не использовать стандартные библиотеки для парсинга `url`?

```py
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urlunparse, ParseResult

url = urlparse('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask')
print(url)
print(urlunparse(ParseResult(url.scheme, url.netloc, '', '', '', '')))
```

Вывод:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='ru.stackoverflow.com', path='/questions/ask', params='', query='', fragment='')
https://ru.stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'/'.join(f"{url}/".split('/', 3)[:-1])
```